# Random rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02 openssl PHP

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to perform RSA encryption on JavaScript and then decode it on PHP.

i followed this tutorial to get the library and perform the encryption on JavaScript:
http://travistidwell.com/blog/2013/02/15/a-better-library-for-javascript-asymmetrical-rsa-encryption/

the ecryption part works fine!

here is the code im using to decrypt from PHP:

```
$msg= "";
if(openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($_POST['data']),$msg,openssl_get_privatekey('file://keys/private.pem'))){
     echo $msg;
}
else{
     echo openssl_error_string();
}
```

my problem is that sometimes the decryption works perfectly but somtimes i got the error:

```
error:0407106B:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02
```

Note: the decryption using the JavaScript function works. If the PHP problem is unsolved is there a way i could use the JS function in the PHP page for decryption?

thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt it? If you mean it's for security, it isn't. You exposed the source code to the user. Use SSL/TLS.

Comment: it is just to have the code in an encrypted format.
the user wont have the private key to decrypt the message.

Comment: He doesn't need to decrypt the message, he can just get the message before it gets encrypted.

Comment: actually im already using SSL but in addition i want to have the data encrypted using this..

Comment: 1. You probably need to `base64_decode()` first. 2. Do **NOT** use PKCS1 padding. Use OAEP or [face cryptographic doom](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/can-you-explain-bleichenbachers-cca-attack-on-pkcs1-v1-5).

Comment: 1. Research how the encoded ciphertext looks like at the client side and the server side (`$_POST['data']`). There are probably some characters mangled such as `+`. 2. Use OAEP. There is a [pull request for JSBN](https://github.com/jasondavies/jsbn/pull/3).

Comment: thanks for the tip.. actually the "+" were being replaced by <space> on the server side!